# How to delete all cell from this table?

Tags: jquery, html-table, cell

```
<table class="Table">
    <thead class="thead">
        <tr class="tr">
            <th class="th header">Done</th>
            <th class="th header">None</th>
            <th class="th header">None</th>
            <th class="th header">Done</th>
            <th class="th header">None</th>

            <tr>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>info</td>
            </tr>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I want to delete all "None"s cell and all "info" of cells

http://jsfiddle.net/D6e4H/

Any idea?

Comment: Hm. So you wanna end up with a table consisting of  Done | Done ?

Comment: check out http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: @Furqan's solutions removes all the `td` with `info` content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
    $(".th:contains('None')") .remove();
    $("td:contains('info')") .remove();
```

Your jsFiddle has been updated.

Comment: OP does not want to remove all info `td`. And what a unique answer. Wow

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this

```
$("th:contains('None')").each(function(index,value) {
    //Grab all the "None" th and their indexes
    $("tr td:nth-child("+$(this).index()+")").remove();
    //remove the td with the same indexes on the next tr
    $(this).remove();
    // now also remove the "None" th
});
```

Here is your [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/D6e4H/10/)

Answer (score 1):

You’re looking for the :contains() selector.

```
$('th:contains("None")').remove();
$('td:contains("info")').remove();
```